# What is eating my beautiful plant?

Tags: sweet-potato

I have a sweet potato, it grown pretty big, and something came and ate it overnight.
There was a small hole, not sure if it is a footprint, or a part of our garden. the radius is about 5 inches.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks more like animal than bug damage. Deer would be prime suspects, there is almost no plant they will not eat. Here, they walk across a wood deck to eat plants in pots. I cut wire fencing into smaller sections and make cages to go around each plant or protect small areas.

Comment: How to solve it is nice, but I want to know what is causing it.

Comment: An animal is eating it, likely a deer.